# Horizontal padding not working with css flexbox on mobile screens

Tags: css, flexbox

I am a newbie in web development. I have encountered two problems, and found solutions to them- but can't explain why the solution works. If someone with more experience can go over them for me, pls. Much appreciated.

I did search all over the net and on stackoverflow and couldn't really find a good explanation. Thanks

1) The problem 1:
I have got thee div's: a parent .title_bar and two child ones: .title_num and .title_text. I center children inside the parent both horizontally and vertically with:
display:flex
align-items:center
justify-content: center

I add padding: 50px to .title_bar for the bar to automatically get taller to accommodate .title_text and .title_num on smaller screens.

If I add flex-flow: row wrap to .title_bar, the items are supposed to wrap for the smaller screen sizes, right? Instead, The end letters in .title_text go beyond the screen on the right.

Code: https://codepen.io/stefanio/pen/vgJLpe?editors=1100#0

HTML:

```
 <div class="instr title_bar">


  <div class="instr title_num">1</div>
  <div class="instr title_text">GUIDEBOOK</div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*top purple bar*/
div.instr.title_bar{
  width:100vw;
  background-color:#670536;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:50px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}


.instr.title_text{
  font-size:3rem;
  padding:10px;
  order:2;
  color:white;
 }
.instr.title_num{
  background-color:#1E091C;
  color:white;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:3rem;
  width:50px;
  height: 55px;
  order:1;
  text-align:center;

}
```

2) Solution to Problem 1:
Added:
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
Inside it, I changed the flexbox to column flow for small screens in order for .title_text and .title_num to wrap successfully. Alternatively, flex-flow: row wrap for smaller screens could also work. I don't really understand why flexbox does not wrap the items automatically here for smaller screens and a separate piece of code has to be added to account for it.

CSS code added to 1) (Sorry, can't post a codepen due to the rules here):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .instr.title_bar{
  flex-direction:column;
    /*
    or flex-flow: row-wrap;
    */
  }
```

3) Problem 2:
If you check the final code at 2) at a small screen size, you'll notice that the .title_text and .title_num are not centered.

4) Solution 2:
If I change padding: 50px to padding: 50px 0 in .title_bar, all of a sudden everything gets properly centered. It looks like the horizontal padding on the .title_bar and justify-content: center; (for row flow) or align-items: center; (for column flow) get in the way of each other- and I did not find a plausible explanation for it either.

Code: https://codepen.io/stefanio/pen/NdvGZY/?editors=1100#0

HTML code:

```
<div class="instr title_bar">


  <div class="instr title_num">1</div>
  <div class="instr title_text">GUIDEBOOK</div>

  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
/*top purple bar*/
div.instr.title_bar{
  width:100vw;
  background-color:#670536;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
  padding:50px 0;
}


.instr.title_text{
  font-size:3rem;
  padding:10px;
  order:2;
  color:white;
 }
.instr.title_num{
  background-color:#1E091C;
  color:white;
  padding:15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:3rem;
width:50px;
  height: 55px;  order:1;
  text-align:center;

}


/*mobile settings (below 500px sceen size)*/
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .instr.title_bar{
  flex-direction:column;
    /*
    or flex-flow: row-wrap;
    */
  }
```

Summary of my problems:
1)   flex-flow: row wrap; in .title_bar not wrapping/ stacking the children as the screen shrinks and 2) align-items:center; in .title_bar breaking down (that is, not horizontally centering anymore) at screen<500px and flex-direction:column; whenever there was a horizontal padding of 50px on the .title_bar (or same goes for justify-content:center; if flex-direction:row; is used). I have solved these problems, but I am curious as to to the cause of these problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a "line-height" attribute to vertically align something inside div. Since the element height that is surrounding "title_num" is set to 55px, then you would add "line-height: 55px" to vertically align something.

```
.instr.title_num{
  background-color:#1E091C;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

To prevent the elements from stacking on top of one another when at 500px screen width and below, just lower the font-size of both items below 500px.

```
/*mobile settings (below 500px screen size)*/
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .instr.title_num,
  .instr.title_text{
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, John D, My problems were: 1) cropping of the last letters in .title_text at screen size<500px ("when "GUIDEBOOK" becomes "GUIDEBOO" at screen<500px) and 2) Lack of horizontal centering of wrapped .title_text and .title_num (when you have "1" sitting above "GUIDEBOOK"- but both are not horizontally centered on the page).

Comment: Hello, John D, Perhaps I was unclear, but I wasn't trying to vertically center the number "1" inside .title_num (I think it was already centered). I also was not trying to fit .title_num and .title_text side-by-side at smaller screen sizes (what you are doing above by decreasing the font size at screens<500px). In fact, I wanted the elements to stack on top of each other at screens<500px. I added a summary of my problems at the end of my question (I'm over the character limit in this box)- please review it. Thanks!

Comment: Hoping this solves your issue: https://codepen.io/johndurso/pen/eb7dbadec231111919e5fa2e977d30ce -- I forked it from you so the styles are the same, I just formatted the HTML differently.

Comment: Hi, johndev. Thanks a lot. I did come up with a solution:https://codepen.io/stefanio/pen/NdvGZY/?editors=1100#0 , but I am curious to why was there a problem in the first place- i.e. why would padding break down the justify-content:center

Comment: Not entirely sure! I rarely use flexbox because I feel like I don't have as much control over it, but that's simply because I'm not well-versed in implementing it. Glad you found a fix, though. @Stefanio